# Mysql JDBC driver ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, mysql

I can't register Mysql JDBC driver in my desktop APP

I download mysql-connector-java-5.1.16.zip

Unzip **mysql-connector-java-5.1.16-bin.jar** and put it into **lib** folder in my app

Add this jar file into Build Path in Eclipse

But Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") throws ClassNotFoundException

Whats wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
}
```

The issue is that `Class.forName(String)` throws an checked exception.  With a checked exception, you can either:

1. Catch the exception.
2. Declare that your method throws the exception. (which is what I suggested above).

Here is an example of catching the exception:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
        //do some exception handling
    }
}
```

Comment: It is clear from his screenshot that Eclipse wants him to either wrap that line of code in a catch/try, or add a Throws to the method signature. His question is why the Driver class cannot be found at runtime.

Comment: @Tanner: I think that zim32 sees the issue in Eclipse and has not even gotten to a point of running the code.

Comment: @zim32 Apparently you are right. Just the way it was worded in such detail way about the class not being found. That mixed with the fact that Eclipse provides hints to solve this, I assumed wrong!

Answer (score 2):

In your lib directory,

1. Right click the jar file that contains your driver.
2. The go to Build-Path
3. Choose Add to build path
4. Run your code again

Also, if you are running JDBC 4.0 compatible driver you no longer need to automatically load your driver. According to JDBC 4.0 specification, section 3.1 under Automatic loading of `java.sql.Driver` says

> `DriverManager.getConnection` has been
>   modified to utilize the Java SE
>   Service Provider mechanism to
>   automatically load JDBC Drivers. This
>   removes the need to invoke
>   `Class.forName`.

Comment: Thank you soo much. After hours of effort, your solution helped me.

Comment: Thanks @Edwin Dalorzo. I was getting error saying "com.mysql" not found when I was loading driver using "Class.forName(com.mysql.jdbc.Driver)" and for this I included MySQL connector jar but nothing working. I was searching for the hours but nothing worked. But when read your answer saying you don't need to load the driver explicitly and commented that line then It worked .

Answer (score 0):

1. You could double check that the jar is really in the Eclipse build path.

   ```
   Project Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries > Add JARS
   ```
2. Try a: `Project > Clean` on the Project menu in Eclipse.