# Java MySQL Connection

Tags: java, mysql, linux, jdbc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mysql JDBC driver ClassNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271453/mysql-jdbc-driver-classnotfoundexception)

I use a function to connect to a MySQL server on Linux which is:

```
protected void connectMYSQL() {
    if (!this.userName.isEmpty() && !this.password.isEmpty() && !this.URL.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); 
            } catch (Exception ex2) {
                 System.out.println("class.forname exception : " + ex2);
                 return;
            }
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, userName, password);
        } catch(SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("can not connect to mysql : " + ex);
        }
    }
}
```

with variables

```
userName = root
password = xxxxxxxxxx
URL = jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/parkDevelop?profileSQL=true
```

but I am getting an error

```
class.forname exception : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

When I remove the line `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();` this time I get error for connection failed.

Comment: Your mysql driver is not found in the classpath. Just add it. There are several [similar questions on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[mysql]+ClassNotFoundException)

Comment: I have added the file mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar in my classpath but I still get this error :/ If I can't solve the problem I'll install the operating system on my server again.

Comment: are you using any ide or using command prompt?

Comment: I am working on command prompt. I also tried java -cp ../src/mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar taksiOperator it doesn't run the jvm.

Comment: @irukera better try absolute path of both jars , while copying might have  missed. [Refer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526048/classnotfoundexception-when-connecting-to-mysql-with-jdbc)

Comment: @irukeru you have "command prompt" on lunix?

Comment: I have solved problem by reinstalling openjdk =)

Answer (score 2):

You need to download the connector from [here](http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/)  and include it in your classpath

Answer (score 1):

You may be missing the [MySQL connector for Java](http://www.mysql.fr/downloads/connector/j/). Add it to your classpath so that your program can locate the class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

Comment: I have downloaded the file and add it to my classpath but still the same problem :/

Answer (score 1):

Your JDBC- MySQL connector driver is not in your classpath. Add the link to mysql-connector-xxx.jar to your CLASSPATH environment variable.

`echo "export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/path/to/your/mysql-connector.jar" > ~/.bashrc`

I also think `URL = jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/parkDevelop?profileSQL=true` should be:

`URL = jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/parkDevelop?profileSQL=true`

Comment: I did this too but still got the same error :/

Comment: 'm curious to know why do we wanna add connector in path? i may be wrong please let me know @Aniket

Comment: @irukeru just add both jar to the classpath it will doesit [see here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/MySQLJava/article.html)

Comment: @Thanga because when we say Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"), that time the JVM searches the classpath to find the correct class. It only searches the path set in CLASSPATH environment variable. If it fails it throws an exception. If it find the .class(in the .jar) it will accept and load the class.

Comment: @irukeru did you actually do that with CLASSPATH?

Comment: `Class.forName()` is no longer necessary: [DriverManager.java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html).

Comment: @Aniket ookies...you may be right :)  yet i didn face any issues as such, just curiosity to know :) thanks fyi

Comment: @Thanga that would probably be because your mysql connector was already in the classpath :)

Comment: @Aniket yeah i have used only in classpath :) thanks for the response

Comment: @Aniket sorry terminal =) I am a bit sleepy =)

Answer (score 0):

This error shows that your mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar file missing in WEB-INF/lib folder. so you add this jar file and restart tomcat server. 
For add jar file use will do first copy that jar file and then paste(ctrl+v) in WEB-INF/lib folder in eclipse.

Comment: I don't see any part in the OP's question mentioning Tomcat. He is trying to access the MySQL database in a simple Java application as far as I understand. He is not mentioning eclipse either...